# Can't load resource script in php page

Tags: javascript, php

I have a subfolder where all the files necessary for the operation of a slotmachine are present. Including under folders with php and js functions. In practice I can not load the functions external to the page is as if you can not connect to the resources even if the paths are right. To be clear, I have the root folder in which the slot folder is present. Inside the slot folder there are sub-folders in particular slots that contains files with the functions php and js with javascripts. Only when loading, the index does not even load these files. How can I improve the code to resolve the issue?

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once ('slots/db.php');
require_once ('slots/users.php');
require_once ('slots/slotsmachine.php');

$userID = Users::LoggedUserID();
if (!$userID) {
    header("location: ../index.php");
        // Decide how to deal with non-logged in people
    //throw new Exception "Not logged in";
}

$userData = Users::GetUserData($userID);
$windowID = rand(); // WindowID is used to identify each Window, in case the user opens more than one at a time, and spins in all of them. Sent straight up to the server.
$machineName = 'default';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Slot Machine</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/slots.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/template5.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="PageContainer">
    <div id="PageContainerInner"> <!-- Just to be able to set the "won!" extra background -->

        <div id="prizes_list">
            <?php
                $prizes = SlotsMachine::ListPrizesForRendering($machineName);
                foreach ($prizes as $prize) { ?>
                    <div id="trPrize_<?php echo $prize['id']; ?>" class="trPrize">
                        <div class="tdReels">
                            <div class="reel1 reelIcon <?php echo $prize['image1']['image_name']; ?>"></div>
                            <div class="reel2 reelIcon <?php echo $prize['image2']['image_name']; ?>"></div>
                            <div class="reel3 reelIcon <?php echo $prize['image3']['image_name']; ?>"></div>
                            <div class="clearer"></div>
                        </div>
                        <span class="tdPayout" data-basePayout="<?php echo $prize['payout_winnings']; ?>"><?php echo (float) $prize['payout_winnings']; ?></span>
                        <div class="clearer"></div>
                    </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>

        <div id="slotMachineContainer">

            <div id="ReelContainer">
                <div id="reel1" class="reel"></div>
                <div id="reel2" class="reel"></div>
                <div id="reel3" class="reel"></div>
                <div id="reelOverlay"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="loggedOutMessage" style="display: none;"><span class="large">Sorry, you have been logged off.</span><br />
                <b>No bids</b> have been deducted from this spin, because you're not logged in anymore.
                Please <a href="/login">login</a> and try again.
            </div>

            <div id="failedRequestMessage" style="display: none;"><span class="large">Sorry, we're unable to display your spin because your connection to our server was lost. </span><br />
                Rest assured that your spin was not wasted.
                Please check your connection and <a href="#" onclick="window.location.reload();">refresh</a> to try again.
            </div>
            <div id="betContainer">
                <span id="lastWin"></span>
                <span id="credits"><?php echo (float) $userData['credits']; ?></span>
                <span id="bet"><?php echo SlotsMachine::MinBet($machineName); ?></span>
                <span id="dayWinnings"><?php echo (float) $userData['day_winnings']; ?></span>
                <span id="lifetimeWinnings"><?php echo (float) $userData['lifetime_winnings']; ?></span>
                <div id="betSpinUp"></div>
                <div id="betSpinDown"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="spinButton"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="soundOffButton"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var machineName = '<?php echo $machineName; ?>';
            var minBet = <?php echo SlotsMachine::MinBet($machineName); ?>;
            var maxBet = <?php echo SlotsMachine::MaxBet($machineName); ?>;
            var numIconsPerReel = <?php echo SlotsMachine::IconsPerReel($machineName); ?>;
            var windowID = <?php echo $windowID; ?>;
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="slot/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="slot/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="slot/js/soundmanager2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="slot/js/slots.js"></script>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Here is a fuction that generate other error if i go in root folder without subfolder setting

```
<?php

class Users {

    // This function gets called *a lot*, so it must be very quick to run. Cache stuff if necessary.
    public static function LoggedUserID() {
        return isset($_SESSION['ID']) ? $_SESSION['ID'] : null;
    }

    // Must return credits, day_winnings and lifetine_winnings
    // Day_winnings may be implemented in multiple different ways. The server doesn't implement them as-is
    public static function GetUserData($ID) {
        return DB::SingleRow("SELECT credits, AS day_winnings, lifetime_winnings FROM 5fa_users WHERE id = " . DB::DQ($ID) . ";");
    }

    public static function IncrementSlotMachineSpins($ID) {
        DB::Execute("UPDATE 5fa_users SET spins = spins + 1 WHERE id = " . DB::DQ($ID) . ";");
    }

    public static function DeductCredits($ID, $bet) {
        DB::Execute("UPDATE 5fa_users SET credits = credits - " . DB::DQ($bet) . " WHERE id = " . DB::DQ($ID) . ";");
        // If you have any sort of audit for your user's credits, you want to log into that
    }
    public static function IncreaseCredits($ID, $payout) {
        DB::Execute("UPDATE 5fa_users SET credits = credits + " . DB::DQ($payout) . " WHERE id = " . DB::DQ($ID) . ";");
        // If you have any sort of audit for your user's credits, you want to log into that
    }
    public static function IncreaseWinnings($ID, $payout) {
        DB::Execute("UPDATE 5fa_users SET lifetime_winnings = lifetime_winnings + " . DB::DQ($payout) . " WHERE id = " . DB::DQ($ID) . ";");
        // If you have any sort of audit for your user's credits, you want to log into that
        // If you keep track of day_winnings, you probably want to update them here too
    }

    public static function HasEnoughCredits($ID, $bet){
        $userData = self::GetUserData($ID);
        return ($userData['credits'] >= $bet);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are those methods static?

Comment: Have you tried like this while including files `require_once ('./slots/slotsmachine.php');`

Comment: yes i try  but no way.....

Comment: can you send the structure of your folders and subfolders ?

Comment: Sometimes what happens when you have multiple folders like tree structure let say folder1(folder2(folder3(folder4 and so on))) then ofcourse it will make you confuse and you will face these problems like if you are accessing folder4 data in folder1. Try to make it simple don't let it go so deeply, i hope you understand, what i mean ?

Comment: I edit the post whit screenshot of structure there are not so much folder to make error about required folder.
In slot folder there are sub folder called slots and js and here there are required file that i need to be load in index page

Comment: if you are in a root directory means you are accessing `slotsmachine.php` from `index.php` then it should be like this `require_once ('./slot/slots/slotsmachine.php');` or this `require_once ('slot/slots/slotsmachine.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Change these files like this, because you are accessing these files from `index.php` so you first have to go to `slot` then `slots` and then you can access files like `slotsmachine.php`

```
 require_once ('slot/slots/db.php');
 require_once ('slot/slots/users.php');
 require_once ('slot/slots/slotsmachine.php');

               OR

 require_once ('./slot/slots/db.php');
 require_once ('./slot/slots/users.php');
 require_once ('./slot/slots/slotsmachine.php');
```

Comment: try even in this way

Comment: I recive this error message if i try to ad slot/ forlder

PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required './slot/slots/db.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear') in /home3/jcodedes/public_html/slot/index.php on line 3

Comment: If you are using linux then you might have root access issues to some of the files you want to access. you are using lampp ? just like xampp ?

Comment: I'm on bluehost server and i have all permission allow to manage db

Comment: you have you checked wthout space like this `require_once('slot/slots/db.php');`

Comment: yes no way it's too strange
change error messagge

PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required './slot/slots/db.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear') in /home3/jcodedes/public_html/slot/index.php on line 3

Comment: I had faced this error in windows and for that i had to include php path in my enviroment variable, but here you are using another platform

Comment: i go to try without subfolder slot may be i can solve the problem

Comment: Yes bro sorry for not solving your problem

Comment: I have not used bluehost, but for every platforms the localhost has it local root folder where we can manage our projects, is it okay with you ?

Comment: I can't solve nothing just change error message in errorlog file

HP Notice:  MySQL error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS day_winnings, lifetime_winnings FROM 5fa_users WHERE id =' at line 1

SELECT credits, AS day_winnings, lifetime_winnings FROM 5fa_users WHERE id = ;

 in /home3/jcodedes/public_html/slots/db.php on line 95

Comment: I edit post with users function code that generate last error

Comment: I think you have error here `("SELECT credits, AS day_winnings, lifetime_winnings FROM 5fa_users WHERE id = " . DB::DQ($ID) . ";");` here AS is not allowed to use in this way, just remove AS and see the result, because AS is something else means a reserved keyword. make it like this `("SELECT credits, AS day_winnings, lifetime_winnings FROM 5fa_users WHERE id = " . DB::DQ($ID) . ";");` but if you want joining then use correct joining with `AS`